# Swing: JLabel which shortens too long text in the middle

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Normally a left-orientated JLabel shortens text at the right by adding periods, e.g. `Hello wo...`. Anyone knows an JComponent (TableCellRenderer is not sufficient) which can shorten text in the middle (`Hel...rld`), e.g. useful for displaying file names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [LeftDotRenderer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/12/left-dot-renderer/) displays the dots on the left. I know its not what you asked for, but you might be able to use the concepts in the code to create your own.